# Sens de « sinon » au début d’une phrase ?

Tags: sens, usage

J’ai vu parfois « sinon » au début d’une phrase et je crois que c’est semblable à « anyway » ou « by the way » mais je ne suis pas sûr.

ex. « Sinon, t’as vu son nouveau film ? »

On dirait que c’est comme « au fait » ou « au passage ». C’est vrai ça ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sinon** correspond plus à ***otherwise*** ou ***anyway*** qu'à ***by the way***.

Il introduit une rupture dans la conversation alors qu'**au fait** et **au passage** sont plus dans la continuité de celle-ci.